# React hook useCallback without dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Does it make sense to use `useCallback` without deps for simple event handlers?

For example:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(() => {
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('clicked');
  }, []);

  const handleOtherClick = () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <button onClick={handleOtherClick}>Click me too</button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

What are the pros and cons for using `useCallback` in this case?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Purpose of `useCallback` does not depend on if you have dependencies or not. It's to ensure referential integrity. To get better performance. If you need that.

Because for flow having just function or function expression itself make code works well(I mean it does not require us to do any extra action to say referencing actual props etc). So `useCallback` is only about performance.

Say we render pure component(instance of `React.PureComponent` or functional component wrapped into `React.memo`)

```
function MyComponent() {
  const onChangeCallback = ...
  return <SomePureComponent onChange={onChangeCallback} />;
}
```

here if `onChangeCallback` is declared as just a function or arrow expression it will be re-created on each render. So it will be referentially different. And nested child will be re-rendered each time while it does not have to.

Another case is listing this callback as dependency in other `useCallback`, `useMemo`, `useEffect`.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const onChangeCallback = ...;
  return <Child onChange={onChangeCallback} />
}

...
function Child({onChange}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('scroll', onChange);
    return () => document.body.removeEventListener('scroll', onChange);
  }, [onChange]);
}
```

Here we also will have referentially different `onChange` in `Child` without `useCallback`. So `useEffect` will be run each time parent `MyComponent` is called. While we don't need it doing this.

So yes, having empty dependencies list when you don't have actually any dependency is better then declaring function inline without `useCallback` at all.

Comment: but wouldn't it be simpler to just add a top-level `function onChangeCallback`, outside of the pure component? it will also be referentially identical (it will not be re-created on every render), so it will not cause any extra renders

Comment: yes, it will. but then you will need to create anonymous function every time just to pass all the arguments which are defined only inside component code `() => onChangeCallback(arg1, arg2, arg3)` which is rather inconvenient

Comment: yes, but the question is about a function that had no dependencies. wouldn't such a function, by definition, need no arguments?

Comment: right, that makes sense. But I don't think this is typical usecase: to react on some event without any binding to specific component instance(props, state)