# it is fine to use useCallback without dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

For example i have a parent component:

```
let [text, setText] = useState("")

const changeText = useCallback(
    (newText) => {
      setText(newText)
    },[]
  )
return(
  <div>
    <h1>{text}</h1>
    <Chiled changeText={changeText} />
  <div>
)
```

child component

```
const Chiled = ({changeText}) =>{
 return(
  <div>
   <input type="button" value="my text" oncClick={(e)=>changeText(e.target.value)}
   <input type="button" value="your text" oncClick={(e)=>changeText(e.target.value)}
  </div>
 )
}
export default React.memo(Chiled)
```

there are any way better to do this or its ok to keep useCallback without dependencies

Comment: There is no point in this. Just declare your handler directly inside the component's body

Comment: useCallback and React.memo for such simple components is really an overkill.

Comment: its an example of a huge list re-render every state change, is that fine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hook useCallback without dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57294549/react-hook-usecallback-without-dependencies)